# Magento Editng Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Filter_Form

Tags: magento

I need to add some more fields into the Sales order report filter (Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Filter_Form) and also into the result grid below the form. I am unable to do so. Can anyone please help me to do this.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, What i am doing is overriding files that are needed for my task and doing. That way is easy to so so.